# Instead of db based repo, How to use file system based repo in svn server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, subversive

I'm dev a PHP website. If we use file system based repo in server, then we can use it as the website root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file based repo doesn't provide you really readable file contents which you could use for serving them as a website.

Serving a SVN repo via http requires Apache and the according Apache module.

If you are using VisualSVN (as your tag suggests) you will have everything in place already.

If you want to serve your repo without VisualSVN you will need to export your repo content regardless wether it is db-based or file-based.